# How create a scrollable levels map for a game in snake form that goes from level 1 to level 1000

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, user-interface, android-custom-view

Here is the UI I want [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUtG0.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Scrollable levels? Do you mean you want a layout that can be scrolled to see all the 1000 levels? If yes, pls post your current layout code here.

Comment: Problem is in drawing this UI, I cannot draw those circles in snake form connecting them with a line.